# Django pass argument to view from html form

Tags: python, html, django

I have an html page that contains a dropdown selector. I have this encased in a form and I essentially want to just reload the same page with a different value passed in when Update is clicked.

Here is the html:

```
<form action="{% url 'analyze:plot' %}">
<select>
{% for name in x_keys %}
    <option name="x_key_name" id="{{ name }}" value="{{ name }}">{{ name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Here is the view

```
def plot(request, x_key='test_key'):
svg_dict = {
    'svg': get_fig(x_key=x_key),
    'x_keys': ScatterKeysXAxis.objects.all(),
}  # set the plot data
plt.cla()  # clean up plt so it can be re-used
return render(request, 'analyze/plot.html', svg_dict)
```

How do I set the x_key within the view from the html form? Is there a better way to do what I am describing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, using html post request objects.

The html form needs to indicate that it will be 'posting' something, like so:

```
<form action="{% url 'analyze:plot' %}" method="post">
```

Now, anything within the html form can be accessed at the destination url if it has a 'name' attribute. For instance:

```
<select name="x_key_name">
```

The value of this will be whatever option is currently selected on the drop down list.
This data be accessed back in my Django view by doing:

```
x_key = request.POST.get('x_key_name', 'default_if_not_found_value')
```

There is no need to have a method argument for x_key, as the necessary information is in the request object.

```
def plot(request):
```

Hope this can help anyone else!

Answer (score -1):

you are doing a post submission with a form

try this in a view:

```
request.POST.get("nameofvariable", "")
```

variables defined (as below) in the view def are for GET and should be set via the URL pattern:

```
def plot(request, x_key='test_key'):
```

for url based get variables checkout: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#specifying-defaults-for-view-arguments